# How to route view to controllers actions in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `EventController` with 3 action methods with the same name in it:

```
public IActionResult ManageEvent()
{
    var model = new EventManageModel();
    ButaGroupContext context = new ButaGroupContext();

    model.Departments = context.Departments.Select(d => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = d.DepartmentName,
        Value = d.DepartmentId.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    model.SelectEvents = context.Events.Select(e => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = e.EventName,
        Value = e.EventId.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    model.Events = _eventService.GetEvents();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ManageEvent(EventManageModel model)
{
    model.ManagedEvent.EventTime = model.DateTime;
    _eventService.Add(model.ManagedEvent);
    return RedirectToAction("AllEvents");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ManageEvent(int id, EventManageModel model)
{
    model.ManagedEvent.EventTime = model.DateTime;
    model.ManagedEvent.EventId = id;
    _eventService.Update(model.ManagedEvent);
    return RedirectToAction("AllEvents");
}
```

I have different forms inside views. How can I call the method I want from within these views?

I think I need routing for this. But I don't know how can I do this.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Add a new event</h2>
    <form asp-controller="Event" asp-action="ManageEvent" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Event Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.ManagedEvent.EventName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dateTime">Date and Time:</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" id="dateTime" name="DateTime" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label >Department</label>
            <select id="select-height" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                    asp-for="ManagedEvent.EventDepartmentId" asp-items="Model.Departments" required=""></select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Update an event</h2>
    <form asp-controller="Event" asp-action="ManageEvent" asp method="post">
        <div>
              <label >Event</label>
              <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="id"
                     asp-items="Model.SelectEvents" required=""></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Event Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.ManagedEvent.EventName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dateTime">Date and Time:</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="DateTime" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label >Department</label>
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
                    asp-for="ManagedEvent.EventDepartmentId" asp-items="Model.Departments" required=""></select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
```

I tried to give each of methods in the controller different parameters. In the code you can see one of methods parameter is (`EventManageModel model`) and another one is (`int id, EventManageModel model`).

Answer (score 0):

Note: You don't specify a controller class name, I will assume **`AdminController`**.

First of all, a `View` never **calls** a `Controller` method. Indirectly *maybe*, but even then we never call it "calling a controller method".

A `View` renders HTML for the browser, which may then make a call to a URL on your server. MVC will check if that URL is a match for a unique(!) combination of **Verb** (GET, POST, PUT, ...) + **Route**. Both **Verb** and **Route** are defined by you, or if not then defaults are used:

- Missing Verb attribute -> **`GET`** is applied.
- Missing Route definition -> **`Admin/<MethodName>`** will be used (see assumption on top).

Routes can't be distinguished, selected or chosen based on URL parameters. Also it is illegal to define a combination of **Verb** + **Route** more than once, it has to be unique.

You have 3 action methods, but one of the **Verb**+**Route** combinations is duplicated:

1. `public IActionResult ManageEvent()`
   -> Serves **GET /Admin/ManageEvent**
2. `[HttpPost]`
   `public IActionResult ManageEvent(EventManageModel model)`
   -> Serves **POST /Admin/ManageEvent**
3. `[HttpPost]`
   `public IActionResult ManageEvent(int id, EventManageModel model)`
   -> Serves **POST /Admin/ManageEvent** - ERROR: ALREADY DEFINED

All **Verbs** have a well defined meaning. POST is used to "create" or "insert" an item. PUT is used to "update" or "change" an item. We can use this to make the 3rd route unique again:

3. `[HttpPut]`
   `public IActionResult ManageEvent(int id, EventManageModel model)`
   -> Serves **PUT /Admin/ManageEvent**

And then update the `<form>` accordingly:

```
<form asp-controller="Event" asp-action="ManageEvent" asp method="put">
```

Comment: Or make sure the other action is `Post /Admin/ManageEvent/{id}`.